# tomcat or apache automatically encodes redirect url

Tags: apache, tomcat, urlencode

I have a simple redirect in my Spring controller as follow:

```
if (url != null) {
    String username = request.getParameter("j_username");
    if(username != null) {
         username = URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
    }
    url = url + (url.contains("?")? "&":"?") + "j_username=" + username;
    getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, url);
}
```

The username should be prepopulated in the next form. This works fine in my local jetty and dev(Tomcat) environment (username shows up as "abc@mysite.com" correctly).  But when it gets to QA which is on apache/tomcat, the username gets double encoded, it shows "j_username=abc%2540mysite.com" on the browser address bar and it shows as "abc%40mysite.com" on the form. Never seen this problem before.  Any pointers? thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `org.springframework.web.util.UriUtils.encodeQueryParam(String, String)` for encoding query parameter, `URLEncoder` is just too generic and does not know the context you're in.